# Get number of predecessors and successors in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of objects, and I want to count the number of previous and next indexes from a given value, up to a certain maximum count.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 460
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 484
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 485
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 486
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 489
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 501
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 654
)
```

**Case: maximum count is 2**

- If the value is **460**, the previous index count **is 0** (as `[0]`) and the next index count **is 2** (as `[1]` and `[2]`)
- If the value is **485**, the previous index count **is 2** (as `[0]` and `[1]`) and the next index count **is 2** (as `[3]` and `[4]`)
- If the value is **501**, the previous index count **is 2** (as `[3]` and `[4]`) and the next index count **is 1** (as `[6]`)
- If the value is **654**, the previous index count **is 2** (as `[4]` and `[5]`) and the next index count **is 0** (as `[6]`)

How can I get these two counts when an array, a value and a maximum count is given?

Comment: please make it more clear what you're trying to do. I couldn't understand what you're trying to achieve or how the "prev" and "next" are calculated.

Comment: Sory @Ali, i confused to how make the code to try it.

Comment: Get the array index of the entry you look for. This minus one is the number of entry before. If this is less then 0 then put it equal to 0. Same logic for next starting from array length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to know whether there are 2 elements before and after the element with the value you search, and if not, how many there are (0 or 1).

Here is a function you could use:

```
function getPrevNext($arr, $find, $max = 2) {
    foreach($arr as $i => $obj) {
        if ($obj->id == $find) {
            return [min($max, $i), min($max, count($arr) - 1 - $i)];
        }
    }
    return [-1, -1]; // not found
}
```

It will return two values (as an array), i.e. those prev and next values. If it does not find the value you are looking for, it returns -1 for both.

Here is how you could call it:

```
$arr = [ 
    (object) ["id" => 460],
    (object) ["id" => 484],
    (object) ["id" => 485],
    (object) ["id" => 486],
    (object) ["id" => 489],
    (object) ["id" => 501],
    (object) ["id" => 654],
];

list($prev, $next) = getPrevNext($arr, 484, 2);

echo "prev: $prev, next: $next"; // prev: 1, next: 2
```

Comment: If want get 3 element just change this value? right? `return [min(2, $i), min(2, count($arr) - 1 - $i)];` to `return [min(3, $i), min(3, count($arr) - 1 - $i)];`

Comment: Updated the answer to accept that number as extra argument.